# How is quantifier elimination accomplished in second and higher order logic?

Tags: logic, higher-order-logic, quantifier-elimination

In first order logic we can eliminate existential quantifiers using a second order equivalence relation:

$\forall$x$\exists$y P(x, y) $\iff$ $\exists$f$\forall$x P(x, f(x))

Dropping the existential quantifier on the function gives skolemization. Now we can peform inferences and substitutions more freely.

Is there a skolemization procedure for higher order logic?

$\forall$x$\exists$y$\exists$R$\exists$f (P(x, y) $\land$ Q(f(x)) $\land$ R(y, f(x))) $\iff$ ?

and if there is one does it assume the axiom of choice or some other strong set theoretical assumption? How can we remove alternating quantifiers in second and higher order logic?

Comment: Be careful. Skolemization is _not_ quantifier elimination, despite the fact that a quantifier is eliminated. Given a first order sentence, the skolemization is a second order sentence that is simply "equisatisfiable", not equivalent. See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/980058/169365

Comment: The second-order version with the existential function quantifier is equivalent, though, in full semantics.

Comment: You can freely convert between a Skolemized sentence and the second order equivalence. It converts equisatisfiable to true. The trick is finding the higher order equivalence to begin with, which is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just replace $\forall x \exists y.\phi$ by $\exists f \forall x.\phi[f(x)/y]$ for higher-order formulas $\phi$ in the same way that you did for a first-order formula. The Skolem functions will acquire more and more arguments as you go. The axiom of choice is needed to show that the skolemised formula is equivalent to the original.

Your example would skolemise like this:

$$
\forall x \exists y \exists R \exists f. P(x, y) \land Q(f(x)) \land R(y, f(x))
\Leftrightarrow
\exists y' \exists R' \exists f \forall x.
P(x, y'(x)) \land Q(f(x)) \land R'(x, y'(x), f(x))
$$

where I have made the slight optimisation of leaving $f$ as it is because it is already paramatrized by $x$.

Comment: Any restricted form to do this without the axiom of choice? Also what exactly happens to the functions and relation variable arguments when they become Skolem functions?

Comment: For your first question: what kind of restrictions do you have in mind? For your second question, nothing is transformed into a function in the matrix of the formula that you are transforming: variables get replaced by function applications.

Comment: Can you actually arbitrarily change quantifier order if the quantifiers aren't of the same type, like ∀x∃f P(f(x)) to ∃f∀x P(f(x))?

As to what restrictions on the axiom of choice? I don't know. It seems like a pretty heavy assumption when you go from first order logic to higher order logic and you have to assume choice as part of your proof calculus.